# Codignier could not remove index.php on distant server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter. I removed index.php on localhost successfully but it's not working on distant server.

When I try to call: http://website.com/user/login it gives me [File not found]. But it works when i type: http://website.com/index.php/user/login

I put all files on www folder and  this is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Could anyone help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the .htaccess I use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Have you checked your .htaccess file is correct on the remote server and that it is being read?

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And in your **config.php**:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

This will remove **index.php** from both localhost and distant server.